# Как добавить только цифры и пробелы в input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, form, jquery-ui

Как ограничить вывод символов и их количество в input + через каждые 4 цифры ставить пробел.

Например я ввожу в инпут номер кредитки и мне нужно разделять каждые четыре цифры пробелом кроме последних, 3423 3565 2345 2345 как-то так должно получиться, и ограничить ввод что бы нельзя было вводить буквы точки.

```
var input = $('.onlynum');

input.keypress(function(event) {
    return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57
});

<input class='onlynum' type="text" placeholder='Card num' maxlength="16">
```

Вроде разобрался с тем что бы вырезать символы, но так же и пробел вырезается, вобщем не понимаю как сделать.

Comment: Это делается легко. Но есть уже готовые ответы: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36833366/format-credit-card-number

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
  let value = this.value.replace(/\s+/g, '');
  let isBackspace = e.key === 'Backspace'; 

  if ((e.key.length === 1 && /^[^\d\s]+$/.test(e.key)) || (!isBackspace && value.length === 16)) {
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
  }
  
  this.value = value.split('').reverse().join('').replace(/\B(?=(\d{4})+(?!\d))/g, " ").split('').reverse().join('').trim();
});
```

```html
Insert your card number: <input type='text' />
```

Comment: А удалять как?))

Comment: @NikitaSmith, Да, благодарю!

Comment: Перемещаться стрелками по введенным цифрам нельзя, Home, End не работают, кнопку Delete использовать нельзя.

Comment: Домашнее задание - довести до ума. Хотел было написать вообще класс, с отслеживанием всяких `selectionStart`, а потом понял что для ответа и так сойдёт.

Answer (score 1):

### Самый рабочий вариант

Есть возможность удаления, не выводит лишних пробелом  и можно задавать необходимое количество символов, а так запрещено копирование во избежание ввода недопустимых символов, например, теста.

```js
const input = document.querySelector(".test_inpit");
input.onpaste = (e) => e.preventDefault();
input.addEventListener("keyup", e => {
  if (e.keyCode !== 8 && e.keyCode != 46) {
    let newValue = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, "");
    newValue = newValue.replace(/(.{4})/g, "$1 ");
    e.target.value = newValue;
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" class="test_inpit">
```

Если хочешь использовать максимальное длину для ввода:

```js
const input = document.querySelector(".test_inpit");
input.onpaste = (e) => e.preventDefault();
const stringLength = 16; // Длинна строки без учета пробелов
input.maxLength =
  stringLength % 4 === 0 ?
  stringLength + (Math.floor(stringLength / 4) - 1) :
  stringLength % 4 !== 0 ?
  stringLength + Math.floor(stringLength / 4) :
  null;

input.addEventListener("keyup", e => {
  if (e.keyCode !== 8 && e.keyCode != 46) {
    let newValue = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, "");
    newValue = newValue.replace(/(.{4})/g, "$1 ");
    e.target.value = newValue;
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" class="test_inpit">
```

Или просто задать это значение в `maxlength` с учетом пробелов:

```
<input type="text" class="test_inpit" maxlength="19">
```

Comment: Самый рабочий, а вводишь хоть сотню символов.

Comment: @Other суть в том что работает, как надо

Comment: Чем он работает нормально? Не один из ответов, не работает нормально, так-как, я мышкой могу вставить, что угодно и даже буквы.

Comment: @And ну в твоем примере тоже самое

Comment: В моем примере? Где это интересно мой пример?

Comment: @And перепутал тебя с Aid, копирование исправлено

Comment: Зачем всегда появляется последний пробел? Как-то не совсем правильно.

Answer (score 0):

Все очень просто. Вешаете событие на инпут - keyup, так как нам интересен момент когда уже введен символ (keypress и keydown срабатывают до того как символ будет записан в инпут, если ставить их - то нужно еще добавить setTimeout). А дальше при срабатывании этого события берем значение самого этого инпута, убираем из него все символы которые не являются цифрами, а дальше уже пробегаемся по строке - и после каждых 4-х символов вставляем пробел (первые 3 раза, дальше нам пробелы не нужны). И в итоге получается отформатированный номер карты.

Т.е. суть в том, что пускай он вводит что хочет - но оставим мы только цифры, а затем отформатируем их так, как нам нужно.

```js
document.querySelector('[name="card"]').addEventListener('keyup', function(){
    this.value = formatCard(this.value);
});

function formatCard(card){
  var digits = card.replace(/[^0-9]/gi, ''),
        result = '';
  for (var i = 1; i <= digits.length; i++){
    result += digits[i-1];
    if (i % 4 == 0 && i / 4 <4 && i != digits.length){
      result += ' ';
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

```css
input{
  width:300px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="card">
```

Comment: Напишите 4 цифры и попробуйте стереть, не зажимая Backspace.

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko элементарно добавить еще одну проверку в условие добавления пробела. Но если уж вы настаиваете, то я добавил это условие.

Answer (score 0):

> Как ограничить вывод символов и их количество в input + через каждые 4 цифры ставить пробел.

```js
var input = document.querySelector('input');
// 8 Backspace; 46 Del; 36 Home; 35 End; 37 <-; 39 ->
var exlude = [8, 35, 36, 37, 39, 46]; // White listed keyCodes
input.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  var code = e.keyCode
  // Не цифры и белый список не пройдет
  if (!(code >= 48 && code <= 57) && !!!exlude.find(k => k === +code)) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
  var len = e.target.value.length
  // Добавит пробелы
  if ((code >= 48 && code <= 57)) // Только цифры
    if (len % 5 === 0 && len < 20 && code !== 8)
      e.target.value += " "

});
```

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <input class='onlynum' type="text" placeholder='Card num' maxlength="20" title="A credit card number" name="card" pattern="[0-9]{16, 20}" required>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Зачем в конце лишний пробел?

Comment: @Other благодарю, убрал. =)

Comment: если перовым символом ввести букву и продолжть вводить цифры посмотри что будет

Comment: @NikitaSmith благодарю, исправил. =)

Comment: @KostaB. сейчас пробел в начале появляется, а так норм)

Comment: Перемещаться стрелками по введенным цифрам нельзя, Home, End не работают, кнопку Delete использовать нельзя.

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko благодарю, внес изменения.

Comment: Можно взять и убрать через дебагер ваш паттерн и писать, что душе угодно. Не съедобно.

Comment: @And а вы доверяете юзеру настолько, что не проводите серверной проверки? На клиентской стороне можно сделать всё, что угодно с вводимыми параметрами и т.д. Суть вопроса не в этом.

Comment: Не все смогут редактировать `js` в браузере без знаний, а вот убрать `pattern` вообще труда не составит и сервер тут не причем в данный момент, хотя минуя сервер конечно же делать не стоит.

Comment: @And вы кроме `HTML`, дальше не смотрели? У меня в примере `HTML`, это как добавочная проверка, все и так сделано в `JS`. Благодярю, что уделили время.